# Jekyll posts not listed on website. How to fix?

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm building a website for the first time with Jekyll and I've been following the step-by-step tutorial laid out in the Jekyll documentation. I've created the posts, layout and post list (`blog.html`) as outlined in [step 8](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/08-blogging/), but when I run `jekyll serve` in my command line my posts are not listed at `blog.html`. What could be the reason for this?

Here is my `_config.yml` file (using the [default configuration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/) laid out in the doc):

```
# Where things are
source              : .
destination         : ./_site
collections_dir     : .
plugins_dir         : _plugins # takes an array of strings and loads plugins in that order
layouts_dir         : _layouts
data_dir            : _data
includes_dir        : _includes
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
collections:
  posts:
    output          : true

# Handling Reading
safe                : false
include             : [".htaccess"]
exclude             : ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "node_modules", "vendor/bundle/", "vendor/cache/", "vendor/gems/", "vendor/ruby/"]
keep_files          : [".git", ".svn"]
encoding            : "utf-8"
markdown_ext        : "markdown,mkdown,mkdn,mkd,md"
strict_front_matter : false

# Filtering Content
show_drafts         : null
limit_posts         : 0
future              : true
unpublished         : false

# Plugins
whitelist           : []
plugins             : []

# Conversion
markdown            : kramdown
highlighter         : rouge
lsi                 : false
excerpt_separator   : "\n\n"
incremental         : false

# Serving
detach              : false
port                : 4000
host                : 127.0.0.1
baseurl             : "" # does not include hostname
show_dir_listing    : false

# Outputting
permalink           : date
paginate_path       : /page:num
timezone            : null

quiet               : false
verbose             : false
defaults            : []

liquid:
  error_mode        : warn
  strict_filters    : false
  strict_variables  : false

# Markdown Processors
kramdown:
  auto_ids          : true
  entity_output     : as_char
  toc_levels        : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  smart_quotes      : lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo
  input             : GFM
  hard_wrap         : false
  footnote_nr       : 1
  show_warnings     : false
```

Comment: Your config looks good, could you also post the relevant parts of `blog.html` and the full path of one of the blog files? The content of that blog file could be useful as well.

Comment: @Ross The content of the `blog.html` file is literally the same as outlined in the [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/08-blogging/) and it's located in the root directory. The posts are located in the `_posts` directory.

Comment: @Ross Carefully combed through `_config.yml` to find any errors and seems the `collections_dir` statement was somehow impeding the listing of the posts. I removed it and they're now showing up in `blog.html`.

Comment: Nice, just a note to future readers, if you have a `collections_dir` set, your `_posts` folder should be inside of it.